# Yii2, хранение в app

Tags: php, yii2

Здравуствуйте
Хочу в любой точке приложения иметь доступ к `app->currentCompany`, где будет компонент с моделью.
Делал по мануалу, но данные не сохраняются в `app->currentCompany`.
Код:
config\web

```
        'currentCompany' => [
            'class' => 'app\models\company\CurrentCompany',
        ], ....
```

CurrentCompany

```
class CurrentCompany extends Component
{
    private $_model = null;

    public function setModel($id){
        $this->_model = Company::getCompanyById($id);
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->_model;
    }
```

в одном контролере задаю `Yii::$app->currentCompany->setModel(1)` и во view получаю правильно `Yii::$app->currentCompany->getModel`, но при этом после переходя на другую страницу данные теряются.
как это исправить? чтобы в одном месте сделать `setModel` и данные оставались во всем приложении

Comment: *"чтобы в одном месте сделать setModel и данные оставались во всем приложении"* --- они и сейчас доступны всегда, *если не перезагружать страницу* ......... а в ином случае надо где-то хранить данные - кэш, файл, БД, Сессия - это уже на выбор......... к фреймворку отношения это не имеет совершенно, так устроен ПХП

Comment: при переходе на другой контролер, данные теряются говорю же.  т.е. без сессии или кеша app не хранит данные если их туда пихнуть?

Comment: *"при переходе на другой контролер, данные теряются говорю же"*  --- а я говорю **хранит!**  но при одном конкретном условии. Вы видимо не внимательно прочитали комментарий

Comment: А если хочется передать данныз из одного контроллера в другой без перезагрузки страницы а во время "одного визита" то можно использовать вызов экшна контроллера через `runAction` -  https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-controller#runAction()-detail  ..